# Why couldn't Peter use his suit at the end

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

I just watched the movie *Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 2* last night. The end of the movie is a bit hazy so maybe there is some detail that I don't remember.

In the first movie, they showed that Peter can use his suit in the vacuum of space and survive. He used it to exit the prison and again to save Gamora at Knowhere.

I'm wondering why Peter couldn't use his suit/mask at the end of the 2nd movie

> instead of Yondu giving him the only space suit left.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this question is being down voted so much? I didn't remember that particular plot point until reading the answer, so he's not the only that might need clarification.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No images or video are available at this point, but while

> fighting Ego,

Star-Lord is slammed into the ground. His helmet can clearly be seen breaking and falling off.

Comment: It was clearly, visibly damaged beyond use, too, and came off his face. Huge crack, and IIRC, one eye completely destroyed.

Comment: MCU Wiki says "The helmet was destroyed when Ego knocked it off Quill's head and crushed it in his hands." Can't recall if that's completely accurate, I remember Ego crushed the walkman. Seems right though. Basically, Ego broke it.