# What is the maximum volume of a space suit?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In the end of Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2, we are treated to (major spoilers)

> the death of another parental figure.

Similar to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/159279/72222), I wonder if a different resolution could have been possible from an in-universe perspective (I'm aware of the outer reasons that flew into the decision to move on with this).

> When they use the space suit, was there any particular reason they couldn't both fit in?

Drax, who is considerably bulkier, fit in a space suit of the same type earlier easy enough, and the layout probably suits even more voluptuous people.

> Wouldn't it make more sense from a designer's perspective to have that sort of auto-adjusting suit cover the entire mass it was attached to, and couldn't two dudes snuggle up close enough to fit inside one?

Just wondering.

Comment: I would make more sense. But this movie does not bother with logic. Or at least not a classical logic.

Comment: Yeah, I know trying to apply logic to such sort of movies is futile, but some consistency is a feature, not a bug. Plus, if we didn't try to apply logic to works of science fiction and fantasy, this site could probably shut down ;-)

Comment: Yes, but this movie has married a cartoon logic with a classic marvel movie logic (not saying that as a negative, it is clearly a choice). Neither of this logics are great on "details".

Comment: The maximum volume is 10. Unless you have [modified equipment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xgx4k83zzc)

Answer (score 3):

### It's irrelevant—the suit only encapsulates the original wearer.

It's inaccurate to think of those space suits as a bag-like volume.  They unfurl exactly around whoever puts one on and appear to adhere pretty tightly.  Recall earlier in the movie, when Drax used one to perform an EVA from the *Milano:* He attached that restraining cable to his belt before donning the spacesuit, and the spacesuit just sealed around the cable anchor.  And in the scene you're wondering about,

> remember that Yondu was holding onto Peter the whole time and the suit sealed around Yondu's arms just like it did with Drax and that anchor.  If Yondu were holding onto Quill any closer, the suit would have still done the same thing.
>
>  It's likely possible for the suit technology to create a bag that two people can share, but these particular suits are not designed to work that way, even if it is possible.