# Why couldn't Peter take off the space suit?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

Near the end of *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* we see Yondu and Peter ejected over a dying Ego, with Peter wearing the only space suit, in this time he scrabbles at his chest to take off the disk projecting the suit but is unable to switch it onto Yondu and save his life.

**Why couldn't Peter take the space suit off and save Yondu?**

Well, I could not find this topic discussed anywhere, but the person wearing the suit should probably be able to take it off on his/her own. So I find it kind of weird Peter was unable to take it off. I doubt Yondu hacked it to make it work like that, therefore the only reason I can find is that it was a failsafe, in order to prevent taking it off unintentionally in a life-threatening environment. So was there some official statement on this from  the filmmakers, or does everyone presumes like me that it was due to the failsafe?

Comment: Because then he, himself, would die. [His own personal suit had already been destroyed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/159279/5184).

Comment: @phantom42 he obviously wanted, but couldn't. The device did not let him deactivate itself. Why? I have a theory, that seems pretty reasonable, but would like to know what others think, since like I said, could not find it discussed anywhere

Comment: Your question is confusing. Can you please specify exactly which movie and which scene you're referencing.

Comment: Yondu puts the space suit on him and the contraption is now inside the suit. Maybe he put it on "the wrong way round" to prevent him from taking it off easily. Though that sounds kinda daft

Comment: Nothing useful in the commentary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have watched the scene multiple times, and paused it frame-by frame, and can, through observational means, deduct one of two possibilities:

1. The suits cannot be opened in space. This would actually make a great deal of sense, as it could prevent someone of ill intent from harming the wearer.
2. Yondu may have purposely put the device on backwards to prevent Peter from removing it. This would also make sense, as the suit would most likely trap the device if put on incorrectly.

However, since there is no mention of Drax or Gamora having to cut the suit off of Quill later, personally, I think possibility 1 is probably the most probable.

Comment: I find the assumption that a device like that has a "backwards" AND that it can be put on backwards (with the result being unable to remove the device) to be a pretty big stretch.

Comment: I also incline to possibility one, because it might be possible that it does hold the atmosphere inside (and recycles the CO2) and repeated activation in vacuum would have left you with vacuum inside the suit as well.